# Stop Excel Scientific Notation Conversion

Tags: excel

Is there a way to **STOP EXCEL** from converting data into Scientific Notation?

Microsoft Excel apparently assumes that any data that contains numbers and an E is supposed to be scientific notation and converts it.

> **17195E000039** automatically changes to **1.7195E+43**
>
> **17221E000112** automatically changes to **1.7221E+116**

Is there a way to prevent Excel from doing this so it doesn't continue to cause problems for all of us users who **never want to use SCIENTIFIC NOTATION ever**? I cannot foresee **any time** where I will **EVER** want to have anything converted to scientific notation. This useless functionality only causes problems.

How do I stop Excel from trying to convert text into scientific without manually performing some operation first?

Unfortunately, the data comes from another system that exports to excel that I cannot change. I cannot manually change the page beforehand and going through afterwards sucks.

Comment: You need to set the column to `Text` before entering or importing the text.  So you will need to get with the people that are doing the export and have them format the cells properly before importing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to STOP EXCEL from converting data into Scientific Notation?

As explained by [@Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner): For you, No.

This is something that happens automatically when the data is written - by the time you see it it is too late.

Answer (score 1):

Issue also occurs with simple strings (eg "1E6" from microtitre plates). I don't think it's a simple as `pnuts` or `Scott`'s responses.

See similar Q I just posted with more detail, toy reprex example, and trial solutions that have failed. [How to stop csv files converting characters (eg plate well IDs 2E6) to scientific notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754486/)