# MS Access VBA Update Excel data to pevent scientific notation (e+ numbers) and import data from Excel files

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Hello I am new in Visual Basic. I have to import data from Excel files (100+ files) located under various folders into Access DB.

Something like these:

D:\Orlenko\Svilupo\VBA_DMO_DATI_LOGISTICI\DATI LOGISTICI\HOME CARE
D:\Orlenko\Svilupo\VBA_DMO_DATI_LOGISTICI\DATI LOGISTICI\PERSONAL CARE
D:\Orlenko\Svilupo\VBA_DMO_DATI_LOGISTICI\DATI LOGISTICI\PET

each underfolder has excel files.

I use Access VBA for this

Somewhere I found how to loop thrue folders and Excel workbooks and adapted it (that part of code isn't mine)

The real problem was to manage scientific numbers (8,00585E+12) EAN for example. If excel has saved a value like text there is no problem it is imported corectly but if it was saved as a number it is always imported like scientific notation to access and after that when you convert a nomber last 2 digits are lost. The only way I found to bypass a problem is to modify Excel data, I put E_ as a prefix to every cell:

```
     'update first 10k rows column B add prefix E_ ( no more scientific notations!:D )
     'prefix "'" do not work 0_o
     Set Rng = objWs.Range("B1:B10000")
     For Each Cel In Rng.Cells

        If Cel <> "" And Left(Cel, 2) <> "E_" Then
        Cel.Value = "E_" & Cel.Value
        'MsgBox Cel.Value
        End If

     Next Cel
     Set Rng = Nothing
```

**The question is there any way to specify variable range of Excel cells to optimise time and memory use during script execution?**
Cells may have null values inside. I am looking for some command to select a range till the last value

> Set Rng = objWs.Range("B1:B10000")

Entire program:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Dim fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, oFile, q_sql, queue As Collection
    Dim objEx As Object
    Dim objWb As Object
    Dim objWs As Object
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cel As Range
            
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set queue = New Collection
queue.Add fso.GetFolder("D:\Orlenko\Svilupo\VBA_DMO_DATI_LOGISTICI\DATI LOGISTICI\")

Do While queue.Count > 0
    Set oFolder = queue(1)
    queue.Remove 1 'dequeue
    '...insert any folder processing code here...
    
    For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
        queue.Add oSubfolder 'enqueue
    Next oSubfolder
    
    'MsgBox (oFolder)
    
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        '...insert any file processing code here...
        
      If InStr(1, oFile.Name, ".xlsx") Then

        Set objEx = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        
        Set objWb = objEx.Workbooks.Open(oFile)
      
       For Each objWs In objWb.Worksheets
            
         'update first 10k rows column B add prefix E_ ( no more scientific notations!:D )
         'prefix "'" do not work 0_o
         Set Rng = objWs.Range("B1:B10000")
         For Each Cel In Rng.Cells
            
            If Cel <> "" And Left(Cel, 2) <> "E_" Then
            Cel.Value = "E_" & Cel.Value
            'MsgBox Cel.Value
            End If
            
         Next Cel
         Set Rng = Nothing
         
         'update first 10k rows column B add prefix E_ ( no more scientific notations!:D )
         'prefix "'" do not work 0_o
         Set Rng = objWs.Range("N1:O10000")
         For Each Cel In Rng.Cells
            
            On Error Resume Next
            If Cel <> "" And Left(Cel, 2) <> "E_" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Cel.Value = "E_" & Cel.Value
            'MsgBox Cel.Value
            End If
            
         Next Cel
         Set Rng = Nothing
         
        'save updated excel file
         objWb.Save
        
        'download from excel sheet
        q_sql = "insert into TB_tot_Excel " & _
                "select """ & oFile & """ as F0, """ & objWs.Name & """ as F_Sheet, * " & _
                "from [" & objWs.Name & "$] in """ & oFile & """ [Excel 12.0; HDR=NO; IMEX=1; Allow Formula=True] "
        CurrentDb.Execute q_sql

       Next
        
        'close opened excel
        Set objWs = Nothing
        objWb.Close
        Set objWb = Nothing
        objEx.Quit
        Set objEx = Nothing
      End If
                  
    Next oFile
       
Loop
'end excel task in windows
'Shell ("TaskKill /f /im excel.exe")
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Comment: So what's the question, the scientific notation or the range definiton?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question has been asked and answered many times before. A quick search of the existing answers may prove much faster than waiting for an answer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=excel+scientific+notation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop Excel Scientific Notation Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270311/stop-excel-scientific-notation-conversion)